# Windows Form Design Change Upon Publish

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Have just seen this behavious , when I tested the application on debug mode it shows the button but when it is deployed the button gets hidden ,

**DEBUG**

[image]

**PUBLISHED**

[image]
[image]

cannot figure out why this is happening  ,given that the machine is same where it is deployed.

Comment: There are other differences as well. The font is larger in Debug so the text "Customer Management" is truncated, and letter 'g' in "Current Page No.: 1" is also cut off on the bottom.

Comment: exactly but the code is not different

Comment: Have you noticed that the screenshots of your app, when *published*, are a little blurry? That's the *virtualization effect*. Your app is not DpiAware. Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103), enhance with: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)